# $\lim_{k \to \infty} \langle s_k,e_n \rangle = \langle h,e_n \rangle$

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, orthonormal

I took a passage from a textbook regarding equivalent conditions of having an orthonormal sequence in a Hilbert space H. Why is the equality

$$\lim_{k \to \infty} \langle s_k,e_n \rangle = \langle h,e_n \rangle$$

true?

In the image below, I highlighted this equality in a red box.

[image]

Comment: Typesetting note: use `$\langle h,e_n \rangle$` instead of `$<h,e_n>$`.  The two results side by side: $\langle h,e_n \rangle~~~<h,e_n>$.

Comment: If $\|s_k-h\|\rightarrow 0$, then, for fixed $n$, $|(s_k,e_n)-(h,e_n)| = |(s_k-h,e_n)| \le \|s_k-h\|\|e_n\|\rightarrow 0$ as $k\rightarrow\infty$.

Answer (score 2):

Let $k\ge n$. Then by construction of $s_k$
$$
\langle s_k,e_n\rangle = \langle \sum_{i=1}^k c_ie_i,e_n\rangle =
c_k, 
$$
where the latter equality follows from orthonormality of the $e_n$.   Now $c_n = \langle h,e_n\rangle $, and the claim follows.

Comment: I do see why we ultimately want $\langle s_k,e_n \rangle = c_n$ for large enough $n$, but please elaborate. All I understand so far is that $$\lim_{k \to \infty} \langle s_k,e_n \rangle = \lim_{n \to \infty} \left\langle \sum_{n=1}^k c_n e_n,e_n \right\rangle = \sum_{n=1}^\infty c_n \|e_n\|^2 = \sum_{n=1}^\infty c_n.$$

Comment: Write the sum with a different index (i.e. $i$), then use orthogonality $\langle e_i,e_n\rangle = \delta_{in}$.

Comment: Oh, right, orthogonality. Here is my approach now: $$\lim_{k \to \infty} \langle s_k,e_n \rangle = \lim_{k \to \infty} \left\langle \sum_{m=1}^k c_m e_m,e_n \right\rangle = \sum_{n=1}^\infty c_m \langle e_m,e_n \rangle = c_n \langle e_n, e_n \rangle = c_n.$$ Is this correct?